# How to actually reduce the used range of a sheet (Excel add-in)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

My addin deletes a lot of rows from each sheet, but when I press `ctrl + end`, the cursor still moves to the last cell of the initial range, which is now empty. Here's an abridged version of what I'm doing:

```
const used_range = sheet.getUsedRange()

const rows = used_range.rowCount
const columns = used_range.columnCount

const full_content = this.format(used_range) // returns a new matrix of values, but with some rows removed

used_range.clear()

sheet.getRangeByIndexes( 0 , 0, full_content.length, columns ).values = full_content
sheet.getRangeByIndexes( full_content.length, 0, (rows - full_content.length), columns ).delete('Up')

await context.sync()
```

The second `sheet.getRangeByIndexes` contains the leftover range. If I set a color for the fill, I can see the range selected is correct, so I would expect that calling `delete('Up')` would delete the rows so that they are not part of the used range anymore, but the last row of the sheet is still the one from before deleting them. This is a problem because even though they are empty, these rows contribute to the file size.

Interestingly, if I do `used_range.delete('Up')` and press `ctrl + end`, cell A1 is selected.

Is there a way to force the sheet range to be reduced? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried UsedRange.Delete instead of Clear? As Clearing a cell is not the same as deleting it....

Comment: Please note that if a range in an excel sheet is reduced, this sometimes doesn't reset until the file is saved.

Comment: @Xabier I'm deleting the range using `Range.delete` at the very end. The `clear` is just to empty out the range so I can set new values.

Comment: @Plutian that was the problem! Closing and opening the file again did reduce the range. If you want to set this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting (previously used) cells from excel, the used range doesn't necessarily reset right away. I'm not entirely sure why as I'm struggling to find the documentation on it, but it is most likely since the last action is still reversible.

To get around this you can save the file, or close and open it again. Excel will then recalculate the used range properly and it will display as expected.

Edit: It's a fairly common issue called "Ghost Cells", it has most likely to do with the cells still existing in memory.

Comment: Excel has been like this since 1990. I can't tell you why, but I know it's been like that for a long time.